# URL redirect not working with .htaccess not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, limesurvey

I am trying to provide better URLs to couple of the Surveys which I have hosted in my server.

So here is what I did.

- In the /var/www directory of the server, (in the same location of index.php file resides), I created a file .htaccess.
- Below is the content of the .htaccess file:

  ```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule goodURL BadURL
  Redirect goodURL BadURL
  ```

Please note that goodURL (midnightsun.hiit.fi/socialnetworking) is something which does not exist, where as BadURL(midnightsun.hiit.fi/limesurvey/index.php/755819) is something that exists.

The reason I want to change this URL redirect is to provide good URLs.

Debian GNU/Linux 7.6 (wheezy) is the OS on the server.
It is Apache2.

Can any one help me with this?

Comment: Use one of these but not both: 1) `Redirect /socialnetworking https://midnightsun.hiit.fi/limesurvey/index.php/755819` or 2) `RewriteRule ^socialnetworking$ limesurvey/index.php/755819`

Comment: And maybe your tool have already a htaccess file (LimeSurvey have one since a lot of year ...). Redirect (before existing rules) is the best way.

Comment: @DenisChenu. Thanks for pitching in. Can you please help me, how it should look like? Currently it is like http://pastebin.com/6h8jMBk3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Redirect temp /liliurl http://example.org/index.php/755819

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    # if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

    # otherwise forward it to index.php
    RewriteRule . index.php
</IfModule>
# General setting to properly handle LimeSurvey paths
# AcceptPathInfo on
```